# How to find ratio between two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

For example

```
df

Cars             Male   female
Ford focus        23      64
vw golf           76      12
ford ka           34      55
renault megane    12      83
```

How do i find the ratio of male to female for every car >0.5

Answer (score 3):

Just subset your data frame using that ratio:

```
df[df$Male / df$Female > 0.5, ]

     Cars Male Female
2 vw golf   76     12
3 ford ka   34     55
```

### Demo

Comment: So if I was just finding ratios for all cars would it be                        
                                                                                                         
      'df[df$Male / df$Female, ] '    ??

Comment: No. `df$Male/df$Female` is likely returning `numeric` (non-integers), but the portions with the brackets needs to return integers referering specific rows or columns. However, `df$Male/df$Female` by itself will give you a vector of ratios. You can save it in your data.frame with `df$Ratio <- df$Male / df$Female`.

Comment: @r2evans that works thanks! I then tried    df [df$Ratio >0.5,]    but is possible to pipe it from highest value to lowest with     sort ?

Comment: Using base R, you'll want to use `order`, perhaps something like: `df2 <- df[df$Ratio>0.5,]; df2[order(df2$Ratio,decreasing=TRUE),]`.

Answer (score -1):

You might try a `which()` function:

```
df[which(df[,2]/df[,3]>0.5),1]
```

Good luck!

Comment: In this use-case, there is no functional difference between `df[,2]/df[,3]>0.5` and `which(df[,2]/df[,3]>0.5)`. The first returns a `logical` vector, the second an `integer` vector, both of which will produce the same results. So for readability and code-golf, I recommend *against* the use of `which` in this code.

Comment: You completely misrepresent what I wrote. It returns that data frame with cars that meet the requirements. Notice the `which()` is in brackets.

Comment: I do not misrepresent it, I said that the use of `which` is extraneous here; it works exactly the same as without `which`. (BTW: `df[...,1]` does *not* return a `data.frame`, it returns a `vector`. Did you try your own code with the OP's data? I don't see a requirement for "data.frame output" in the question, though, so that point is moot.) I'm not trying to discredit you here, I'm trying to inform on the value and function of `which`.